# How do I duplicate a Squarespace Developer mode template?

Tags: squarespace, velo

I'm trying to find an updated website that lays out how to DUPLICATE a site using Squarespace's Developer mode...  It's embarrassing that Wix has this functionality and Squarespace doesn't, but my client likes the Squarespace UI better...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a reference, I found this for Squarespace site duplication:

https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205809768-Can-I-duplicate-a-Squarespace-site-

but with developer tools you're supposed to be able to create templates...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot duplicate an entire website, but you can duplicate the template. I do this a few times per week because I've built a Developer template starting point that I use on every project.

1. **Create a template.** This can be done by downloading an existing template, or creating your own from scratch. I distribute a few of my own Developer templates on my Github, [here](http://github.com/squarefront).
2. **Register a new website.**
3. **Turn on Developer mode.** [Help link](http://developers.squarespace.com/initial-setup). This will enable access via SFTP/Git to your newly created Squarespace website.
4. **Create new project**. I create the project locally by Git cloning my project starting point, which is a combination of my dev tools and developer template.
5. **Upload.** Finally, I Git push or SFTP sync to my newly creating website.

As of then, you should have a duplicate ready for your content. Since Squarespace doesn't have content importing/exporting, you must re-create all of your content.